# FQL or Facebook API: Get only my events created

Tags: facebook-fql

i have this query:

```
select eid from event where creator = 100000956216009
```

Return this error:

> error: 604
>   Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from 
>   http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL_Tables

How i can get all My Created events? TIA
I need to print my events created on my fb account and print it on my External Site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved, my problem is the permission:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Comment: Did you stick with FQL or the API?  The documentation for the event FQL states that only `eid` is `indexable`.  That means the FQL statement you have above shouldn't work, even with permission changes.  You would need the `eid` in your where clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should read http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/events.get

Comment: ok, many thanks, therefor you suggest to me for parsing the result (all events) and check the values for 'creator' if equals to my facebook id ?

Comment: The documentation says you can provide the uid to get events for

Comment: solved, my problem is the permission:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions
user_events
bye.